# Multi-control multi-target gate

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, quantum-control

I'm using qiskit for simulation. Suppose, I have 6 qubits with indices `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I have an operator $U$ of size $4 \times 4$, such that it operates on 2 qubits.

How can we use qiskit to create a multi-control-multi-target gate such that, for example, the control qubit index is `[1]` and target qubit indices are `[3, 4]`? Or control indices are `[0, 1]` and target indices are `[3, 4]` or any other variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a quantum gate from any unitary operator $U$ using [`UnitaryGate`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.library.UnitaryGate) class. And we can add any number of controls to any gate using [`control()`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.Gate#control) method.

As an example, let's create a $4 \times 4$ unitary:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_unitary

U = random_unitary(4)
```

Now, let's apply this operator to qubits $3$ and $4$ controlled by qubits $0$ and $1$.

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import UnitaryGate

circ = QuantumCircuit(6)
circ.append(UnitaryGate(U).control(2), [0, 1, 3, 4])
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: perfectly works, thanks!